# Why are the real numbers with the K-Topology not metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

I will denote the real numbers with the $K$-Topology as $R_{K}$ (If someone doesn't know or remember this topology, read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology)). I understand that $R_{K}$ is not regular, since the set $K$ cannot be separated from the point $0$, and it is second-countable, since you can take as basis the intervals with rational endpoints. It seems to me that this is not enough to prove that $R_{K}$ is not metrizable, but I don't know how to proceed. Someone suggested me to use Urysohn metrization theorem, but I think it is not possible in this case since it is not a characterization of metric spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Every metric space is normal, and hence regular. But the $K$-topology is not regular, thus not metrizable.